# Can i create an object where the value of the property is a randomly generated number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, random

I want to create an array of objects, and in each object, I want to have the key being an item, and the value to be a randomly generated number, how could I go about this?

Comment: which `item` you want to be `key`

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: var array3 = [{  item: 'item name',
        price: (Math.random()*100)}];

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try:

```js
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) arr.push({item: 'item_'+parseInt(Math.random() * 100)});
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, inside a for loop it creates items and assigns random values to them

```js
var a=[];
for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
{
var obj={};
obj.item="item"+i;
obj.value=Math.random()*9;
a.push(obj);
obj={};
}
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"];
const arr = items.map(item => {
    //this object will be returned
 let resultObj = {};
    //set the item as key and random number as its value
 resultObj[item] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
 return resultObj;
})
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Double check your code it looks like it's resulting in an error.

Comment: @Tom O. Thanks it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could create a random number generator in JavaScript (if coding in ES6 or later). The approach below takes advantage of [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). An [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) is returned when you call a generator function. You can then call `next()` on the iterator to get the next value `yield`ed by the generator. The object returned by the call to `it.next()` will have two properties, `done` and `value`.

Since the generator `yield`s a value every time it's called (due to the infinite `while(true)` loop inside the generator function), the `done` property will never become `true`  - this means you can keep calling `it.next()` to get random numbers forever.

```js
init();

function init() {
  const rands = [];
  const it = randomNumberGenerator(100);
  let i = 0;
  document.querySelector('#random').addEventListener('click', e => {
    rands.push({
      id: i,
      value: it.next().value
    });
    i += 1;
    log(rands);
  });
}

function* randomNumberGenerator(max) {
  while (true) {
    yield Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }
}

function log(o) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(o);
}
```

```html
<input id="random" type="button" value="Add random number object to array" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable such as `amount` which specifies how many objects you would like to have.

Then use a `for` loop to add your object based on the `amount` of times you have specified.

To add an object to an array you can use `arrayName.push()`.

To get a random number, you can use `Math.random() * 100`. Here `10` is the max number you can get as a random number. If you want these numbers to be integers you can use `~~(Math.random() * 100)`

See working example below:

```js
const amount = 3, // The amount of items you want in your array
objects = []; // The array to hold all your objects
for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  objects.push({
    item: Math.random() * 100 // Get a random number between 0 and 10
  }) // adding the object to the objects array
}

console.log(objects); // log the output
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a code example below were You can order random data from a factory just specify how many items you want:

```
const data = new RandomDataFactory('car', 50)
```

if needed you can modify the random function further to have the data random every time it is accessed

```
const random = function () {

return Math.random() * 300

}
```

the sane item from array would return random data every time

```
data[0].speed() === data[0].speed() // false
```

and would not be equal.

```js
class DataGenerator {
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name
    const result = []

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      const name = `${this.name}-${i}`
      const random = Math.random() * 300

      result.push({
        item: name,
        speed: random
      })
    }

    return result
  }
}

const data = new DataGenerator('car', 50)
console.log('random: data', data)
```